# Conditional Formatting AND OR in same column

Tags: google-sheets

I have tried numerous formula combinations in Google Sheets Conditional Formatting to highlight when a "No" answer is entered into cells B3, B5, B7, B8, B9 and B11 when the answer in cell B2 = "Yes".

[image]

I have tried `=AND(B2="Yes",OR(B3="No",B5="No",B7="No",B8="No",B9="No",B11="No"))`

I have also tried `=AND(OR(B3="No",B5="No",B7="No",B8="No",B9="No",B11="No"),B2="Yes")`

The formula is applied to B3, B5, B7, B8, B9 and B11.

Would appreciate help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In conditional formatting set the range to B3:B11 and use as a custom formula:

```
=($B$2="Yes")*($B3="No")*(ISNA(MATCH(ROW($B3), {4, 6, 10}, 0)))
```

And see if that works?

---

### References:

To Learn more about conditional formatting, see: [this link.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NhEqCqt-nl4)

Comment: Thank you very much - that works. And thank you for the link - very helpful